# Select Component in material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement the `Select` component from `Material UI`. But, I am not able to get the text in one line after the select is done.

While selecting:

[image]

After selecting:

[image]

I want the **symbol** and **storage** come in the same line after selecting.

Thanks!

Comment: Paste your code.

Comment: @NearHuscarl, it definitely does :)

Thanks a lot.